# Refinery CMS: generating migrations for existing models within an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration, refinerycms, refinery

I want to add an attribute to a model I've created within a Refinery CMS engine.  I know I could do the following:

1. `rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string`
2. Manually move the migration file from `db/migrate` to `vendor/extensions/products/db/migrate`

But is there a command to generate the migration into the correct folder in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, that's how you do it :-)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to create the migration in your extension's migration folder, then run rails g refinery:<engine_name> to copy it into the project migrations folder?

Comment: I agree with @Cristian -- although perhaps we are looking at a different problem. My situation (which the `rails g refinery:<engine_name>` method solves) is when I have added new migrations to an engine that is already installed in the app

Comment: @parndt when I do this I see the migrations end up in the spec/dummy/db/migrate folder. Is that what we should expect? It's annoying! :)

Comment: That happens when you're using a dummy application, yeah. It's a side effect of that approach.  It's not something that we addressed very well, so the workaround in the question is still often appropriate, though you copy it from spec/dummy/db/migrate/ to the extension instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I have outlined above is correct, according to @parndt ([the lead developer of the Refinery project](http://refinerycms.com/about)).